# Issue with positioning jquery ui tools overlay

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I'm using jquery ui tools overlay plugin, and It almost 100% working, but when I click to open an image and scroll down the image sticks. I quickly found that this is because the script is setting the positioning to fixed. However, when I changed the positioning using the config provided on the documentation http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/custom-effect.html I still get the same results. The site is marccasavant.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more complicated than it appears... Indeed, you **just** need to change the `position` from `fixed` to `absolute`, but as it is done by the overlay plugin, you can't just set this in the css, you need to do it on-the-fly.

The solution i came up with is to declare a custom effect :

```
$.tools.overlay.addEffect("change", function(css, done) {
css.position = 'absolute';
overlay = this.getOverlay();
   overlay.css(css).show();
   overlay.animate({
      top: '+=55',  opacity: 1,  width: '+=20'
      }, 400, done
   );
   done.call();
}, function(done) {
   this.getOverlay().animate({
      top:'-=55', opacity:0, width:'-=20'
   }, 300, function() {
      $(this).hide();
      done.call();
   });
```

});

who just change the css `position` property (and do some animation, that you can obviously change), and do the default stuff. Then add it when initializing the overlay :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("img[rel]").overlay({effect: 'absolute'});
});
```

I used this tutorial: http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/custom-effect.html and just removed their custom drop effect, and add the positioning change.

Answer (score 0):

I used developer tools to change the position to "absolute" and it works as expected. Verify that the config applies absolute position, otherwise use jQuery to modify the css:

```
$('.simple_overlay').css('position', 'absolute');
```

Comment: I tried that as well which unfortunately did not work, I've checked the jquery ui tools site for help with this issue and I've inserted their custom config which does change the positioning to absolute, but for some reason does not solve the problem, as it did in developer tools.

Comment: Try changing it with jQuery, not in the config

Comment: @MarcCasavant indeed, because you need to do this when the overlay is triggered. See my answer for a complete solution.